# cast error->System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Cast'

Tags: c#

hi friend i m getting that error can any one plz help

***'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Cast' and no extension method 'Cast' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)***

Answer (score 2):

It would help if you show your code, but it looks like you're trying something like:

```
var o = myDataGridView.SelectedCells.Cast(...);
```

The error message is telling you that there is not such method named Cast defined on the  SelectedCells object, so you need to look at the line that is causing the error and change it.  The documentation for DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection, which lists all the methods that can be called, can be found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewselectedcellcollection_methods(v=VS.100).aspx

You might also like to read the documentation for the DataGridView.SelectedCells property:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedcells.aspx

Finally, perhaps you have defined an extension method called Cast that operates on a DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection.  For instance:

```
namespace MyLibrary.ExtensionMethods
{
  public static List<Something> Cast(this DataGridViewSelectedCellCollection collection)
  {
    var myList = new List<Something>();
    // code to cast your collection to something and add it to the list
    return myList;
  }
}
```

If so, you need to make sure you are telling the compiler where it can find the method.  In C# you use a using directive:

```
using MyLibrary.ExtensionMethods;
```

In VB it is

```
Import MyLibrary.ExtensionMethods
```